# What creates future-dated civicrm_financial_trxn records, seen in Bookkeeping Transactions report?

Tags: civicontribute, bookkeeping

When viewing the output of the Bookkeeping Transactions report, I'm seeing many contributions listed with repeating future-dated transactions, even though these transactions do not appear when looking at the contributions in  the UI (i.e., viewing a contribution in the "Contributions" tab or Find Contributions search).

A common pattern is that there are several transactions, on the same day of successive months, for the same amount, leading up to several months in the future.

**Update:** as asked in comments, yes, this site has Deferred Revenue enabled.

**Question:** What normal process are there in CiviCRM that create future-dated civicrm_financial_trxn records?

Comment: Oh boy - that does not sound good. Are you seeing this on more than one instance?

Comment: Do you have deferred revenue turned on?

Comment: Pradeep Nayak, yes, Deferred Revenue is turned on here. Does this mean you have an answer? (fingers crossed)

Comment: KarinG, no, I'm seeing this only on one instance.

Comment: Sounds like Deferred Revenue is the answer to your question :-)

Comment: Deferred Revenue is indeed the answer. https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/28931/907 mentions this specifically, "What it does is, instead of creating one transaction for an annual membership, it should basically break it up into twelve monthly transactions." Also the video linked in that question (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNIHXBA6EEg) says so specifically at 46:40. Pradeep Nyak, you definitely deserve points for an answer; if you make such, I'll accept it.

Comment: Does it all add up?

Comment: Yep, the transactions add up to the expected total, and the number of transactions matches the number of months remaining in the (fixed-period) memberships.